# PHP DOMDocument prevents closing tag from being auto-generated if it is not provided

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, domdocument

Currently, my DOMDocument PHP object auto-generates a closing tag if it doesn't exist. I would like to prevent this behavior from happening. Here's an example: `<div><p>text</p>` will add a closing `</div` tag to it.

It's funny because there is a Libxml option called `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`, which actually FORCES it create a closing tag. However, I would like something that is the opposite of that.

Comment: But there must be a solution

Comment: It's not pointless because the "text" is going in a `<code>` tag, so I want to ensure that nothing gets auto generated. How would I do it myself? Not even sure where to begin, as there isn't much DOMDocument help online

Comment: My apologies, I should have specified. Obviously the `<code>` tag itself has nothing to do with it. I am using DOMDocument to simply add htmlspecialchars() to anything in `<code>`, since I am using this to present code. I don't want closing tags to generate in my examples